# Unable to start PlexMediaserver service

Tags: plex

My plexmediaserver.service looks as per following.

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Plex Media Server for Linux
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    Environment="PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR=/var/lib/plexmediaserver/        Library/Application Support"
    Environment=PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_HOME=/usr/lib/plexmediaserver
    Environment=PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_MAX_PLUGIN_PROCS=6
    Environment=PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_TMPDIR=/tmp
    Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/plexmediaserver
    ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkdir -p "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}"'
    ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex\ Media\ Server'
    Type=simple
    User=plex
    Group=plex
    Restart=on-failure
    RestartSec=5
    StartLimitInterval=60s
    StartLimitBurst=3

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and error i get is as per following

```
    ● plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server for Linux
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-12-11 17:15:21 EST; 6min ago
      Process: 4417 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkdir -p "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" (code=exited, status=217/USER)
     Main PID: 3588 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

    Dec 11 17:15:21 ubuntuServer systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    Dec 11 17:15:21 ubuntuServer systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
    Dec 11 17:15:21 ubuntuServer systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    Dec 11 17:15:21 ubuntuServer systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server for Linux.
```

Comment: Do you have any logs from plex?

Answer (score 3):

By doing bit more of research, I could find fix. By executing below 3 commands, it worked.

```
    sudo mkdir /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library
    chmod 777 -R /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library
    service plexmediaserver restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have user `plex` and group `plex` in that os.

Then you can just use `sudo chown -R plex:plex /var/lib/plexmediaserver` to change the ownership of plexmediaserver and its sub directories.

Comment: This is a far better suggestion than changing the `plex` folders to `777`.

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles upon this. My problem was the other way around; I had to change the user and group in the `override.conf` file to enable Plex to get access to other directories...AND...I had to change the ownership of the `/var/lib/plexmediaserver` to the new user also, because otherwise Plex could no longer access it's own directory!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> User=plex
> Group=plex
> ```
>
> ```
> Process: 4417 ExecStartPre= … (code=exited, status=217/USER)
> ```

So create the missing user account, then.

> ```
> Environment="…=/var/lib/plexmediaserver/        Library/Application Support"
> ```

And when you copy and paste things, check them.